# How to add user assigned managed identity to Azure Lab VM?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-lab-services

My goal is to have a VM to run builds for Azure DevOps with a user-assigned managed identity so we can keep everything connectionStringLess.

I have just created an Azure Lab and a VM in it.

The reason for this in the lab is so we can shut it down during nights and weekends.

However, I can't find the option to assign managed identities to it.

[image]

If possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks the lab VM (`Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/virtualmachines`)  does not support MSI currently, you need to use the [azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/)(`Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines`).

Reference - [Services that support managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities).

**Besides**, I notice you use the lab VM for auto-start/stop reason, actually the Azure VM also supports that, see [Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solution in Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management), not only schedule VMs to start and stop, but also other features.